# Deploy QML app to ubuntu phone

Tags: ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-sdk

I'm trying to start a project using the Ubuntu SDK (Qt Creator). I have created a QML project, which has some "Hello world" code in it already. I've done no changes to the code, but just want to learn how to deploy it to my Ubuntu phone. I can run it on my desktop.

Qt Creator gives an error when trying to "run" the armhf debug version. "Could not find 'test2.desktop'", however, I can find that file. And it's located under "Other files" in my project.

[see screenshot attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTUPA.png)

Failing that, I did try to scp the files over to the phone and run it both through ssh (anything like export DISPLAY=:0.0 on mir?) and through the local, on-phone, terminal app. Both gives the following error:

```
phablet@ubuntu-phablet:~/test2$ qmlscene Main.qml 
Loading module: 'libubuntu_application_api_touch_mirclient.so.3.0.0'
UbuntuClientIntegration: connection to Mir server failed. Check that a Mir server is
running, and the correct socket is being used and is accessible. The shell may have
rejected the incoming connection, so check its log file
Aborted
```

Any clues, guides or tutorials would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Change this line in your test2/test2.pro

```
desktop_file.files = $$OUT_PWD/test2.desktop
```

to

```
desktop_file.files = test2.desktop
```

I still got some errors, but deploying works for me now. I am no qmake expert, but I think it looked for the file in the wrong directory.